# Play live streaming video in phonegap

Tags: cordova, video-streaming, live-streaming, strobe-media-playback

I am trying to play live streaming video in phone gap using strobe player but when I am playing it shows nothing. I have no idea where is the error. 
I need to play live streaming video in strobe media playback
my code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Device Detection Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            .movie {
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
            }
            .movie div.thumb {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: solid 1px blue;
            }
            .movie div.details {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .movie div.details p.title {
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .movie div.details p.desc {
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.strobemediaplaybackhtml5.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/profiles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/devicedetection.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.strobemediaplaybackhtml5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/StrobeMediaPlayer.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Faizan/workspace/cordova.js" ></script>


        <script>
            var movies = [
                          {
                          "flashvars":{"poster":"http://www.osmf.org/dev/1.6gm/images/poster1.png", "src":"http://players.edgesuite.net/videos/big_buck_bunny/bbb_448x252.mp4"}, 
                          "element":"clipContainer0"
                          },
                          ];

            $(function() {
              for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
              strobeMediaPlayback.flashvars(movies[i]["flashvars"]);
              strobeMediaPlayback.draw(movies[i]["element"]);
              }
              });

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
           Strobe Media Playback
        </div>
        <div id="movie0" class="movie">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div id="clipContainer0"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="details"><p class="title">Video One</p><p class="desc">Video one description.</p></div>
        </div>

    </body></html>'
```

change the order and cordova.js path but still not showing video
:(

Comment: I am not sure on this line :  <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Faizan/workspace/cordova.js" ></script> . I think  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script> is correct one if you are using phonegap build.

Answer (score 0):

Order of js library is seems to be wrong!. check this new order of JS library.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/profiles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/devicedetection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.strobemediaplaybackhtml5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/StrobeMediaPlayer.js"></script>
```

Also, I am not sure on this line :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Faizan/workspace/cordova.js" ></script>
```

I think

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script>
```

is correct one if you are using phonegap build.